# Transferring a single row into an array & echo it into their respective textboxes

Tags: php

I'm doing a search function where the user need to input ID number in order to search a person's info. I did search the web on how to do this, but I got stuck when transferring the data back. In my case, I want to transfer every data into their respective textbox. For example :

```
fullname => fullname textbox
gender => gender textbox
```

So how do I convert the array into individual php variable and echo it in the textbox? Or there might be any better way? Here is the function on what I've done so far :

```
function userRetrieve ($cardid) {
$cardid = mysql_real_escape_string($cardid);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `card_id` = '$cardid'");
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    if ($row){
        //What should I do here? 
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First thing first, mysql_* functions are depreciated; start looking into PDO or MySqli and you are querying the result set twice `$res = mysql_query($sql)` to get the data you can do `echo $row['fullname'];` and `$row['gender '];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are querying only one user do

```
if ($row){
   $user = new user($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['birthdate'], ...);//if you have a class user,which is adivsable
   //if you do not just save the row or use it like
   echo "User name = " . $row['name'];
}
```

When you query multiple users you can do

```
$users = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){//do not call mysql_query twice
   $users[] = new user($row['id'], $row['name'], $row['birthdate'], ...); //if you have a class user,which is adivsable
   //if you do not, just save the whole row
   $users[] = $row;
}
```

If you use the second option you can access the users like so:

```
foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user['name'];
}
```

the values ['*here*'] should match your column names in the database.

To get the values from the function do

`return $row;`

---

Your function should look like:

```
function userRetrieve ($cardid) {
  $cardid = mysql_real_escape_string($cardid);
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `card_id` = '$cardid'") or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
  if ($row){
     return $row;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

Now you can call your function like so:

```
$current_user = userRetrieve(14); //id example, should be a variable
echo $current_user['name'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That clears thing out a little bit. But how do I retrieve the data from the function? I mean to transfer the data and use it. (Echo the data into textboxes)? Is there anything to do with `return` the value ?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It helps me a lot!